# Does it possibale to Develop an Apple Watch App to and IOS app to Support iOS Watches and other OS Watches

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, apple-watch

I have an iOS Application and am developing an Apple Watch Application for it.

The user should log in first to the iOS app and then we send the "Authentication log-in" to the iOS Watch App and the user can do some calls from its watch.

I'm Working on it as an extension of the main Application. and the Question is...

- What is going to happen if the user has an iPhone and smartwatch which is not Apple?
- Is there a way to send data from the iOS Application to the smartwatch (Android, Galaxy, and Huawei)?
- Can the Application on the (Android, Galaxy, and Huawei) works like the one on the Apple Watch? or does it need a different development?.

Comment: **Apple** software uses `Swift` & `Objective-C`, **Android** uses `Kotlin` & `Java`. The bottom line is, building apps for different `OS` watches or Phones requires different source codes unless you're using another non-native tech (i.e `Flutter`). So if an iPhone user has an android watch (Highly unlikely) or vice versa, the app wouldn't work on both systems without proper implementation.

Comment: Thank You @NoeOnJupiter for your replay...
does it possible to provide this proper implementation to the watches that it's not from apple.... can we integrate it with our ios app?